# AppCache mime type with IIS7

Tags: iis-7, mime-types, mime, html5-appcache

We're hosting a couple of HTML5 games that utilise the `offline.appcache` feature letting games cache a lot better.

To serve the `.appcache` type however, I had to add the mime type to the server (IIS7) so it wouldn't 404.  When I do, it refuses to serve any images or CSS files!  The error sent to the browser when I request a CSS or image file is:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

The extension I am adding is `appcache` with the MIME type `text/cache-manifest`.

Any ideas why it's causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, I added the mime type on server level not site level. One of the sites already had that mime type defined. Which caused a conflict. But bizarrely the site with the dual definition was fine, it was the other sites that failed.

Comment: Can you clarify this?  I added the mime type at site level and it broke all css and js requests, but only for the site I added it to. Any ideas?

Comment: [How to add mime types with IIS7 Web.config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when adding the .appcache.  All .js and .css file requests responded with an error from IIS.  I realized it was because I had not specified a NETWORK: section.

My working .appcache now forces all files to be refreshed and doesn't cause errors:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# cache version 1.0.0.6

NETWORK:
*
```